# qualifying GET requests github api

Tags: github-api

Is there a way to filter github events using the GET request?

For example can I preform a GET that returns a subset (ForkEvents) of a repo's events?:

pseudo-request (though this doesn't work):
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/events?type=ForkEvent

More generally is there any way to implicitly filter the response data in the GET request i.e. before the data reaches my code? (I am new to the github-api and RESTful APIs in general, so I apologize in advance if this is a clueless question)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [Events Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) is correct, it would appear this is in fact not possible. If you're new to the GitHub API you should probably try to use a library that exists for it. For example, if you were using python and [github3.py](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) then you might do something like:

```
import github3

g = github3.login("nelag", "nelag's password")
r = g.repository("nelag", "nelags_repo")
forks = filter(lambda event: event.type == 'ForkEvent', r.iter_events())
```

Nice and simple and you will have the added benefit of your code being lazy.